# if a='4*6' why int(a) not = 24 is there any way to do it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to multiply all members of list

```
i = [6,7]

print(int(str(i).replace(',', '*').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')))
```

I expect the output `42` but error is

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6*7'

Comment: I don’t know Python, but “6*7” is not a valid number. You need to convert each stringified number into to an actual number before attempting to perform math operations. You need `6*7` not `'6*7'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` can't cast the value `'6* 7'`
You can try this with `eval`.
The `eval()` method parses the expression passed to this method and runs python expression (code) within the program.

This will work

```
print(eval(str(i).replace(',', '*').replace('[', '').replace(']', '')))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not even sure why are you converting a list `i` into a string, and then doing the `replace` and `eval`.

A much cleaner way to do it will be to use [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce) which will apply multiplication operator between all elements in the list, this way you can multiply arbitrary long list of integers, the function we use here is [operator.mul](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul), which stands for multiplication, `a*b`

```
In [48]: import operator 
    ...: from functools import reduce                                                                                          

In [49]: reduce(operator.mul, [6,7])                                                                                           
Out[49]: 42

In [50]: reduce(operator.mul, [6,7,8,9,10])                                                                                    
Out[50]: 30240

In [51]: operator.mul(6,7)                                                                                                     
Out[51]: 42
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to multiply a list is using `reduce` from `functools`. Here is the code:

```
from functools import reduce
multiplied_list = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [6,7])
print(multiplied_list)
```

Hope it helps :)